# How to solve this IPv6 looping problem?

Tags: routing, ipv6, tunnel

I have set up a 6in4 tunnel, namely "sit1", but I have discovered that if I traceroute non exist IP within the subnet, it will loop. What should I do to solve this?

The routing table:

[image]

Comment: I'm confused about a `6to4 tunnel`, do you mean you are trying to tunnel IPv6 over IPv4 to a tunnel host?  Also what IPv6 addresses are on this box?

Comment: Yes. My IP address on the tunnel interface is 2001:460:18:c7b::2. And gateway address is 2001:460:18:c7b::1

Comment: As I understand, it's bad idea to assign IP from one subnet to bridge-local and to sit1

Comment: What would be a better solution?

Comment: Were you assigned another /64 (or a /48 to use internally) by the tunnel broker?

Comment: Yes. Another /64 network

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tunnel is a point-to-point interface, all packets sent over the tunnel are received and processed by the remote device.  When the remote device realizes the packet is destined for a subnet-local address it sends it back across the tunnel to your Microtik. You are hitting a the [ping-pong vulnerability](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-ipngwg-p2p-pingpong-00) in IPv6.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be to refrain from assigning a prefix to the point-to-point link, and to use a link-local address as the next hop.

Comment: We don't always have this option. With this tunnel, in particular, the global address is always assigned, and the link-local address of the other endpoint may not be available.

Comment: Then you can hack around the issue by adding some firewall rules to drop the offending packets.  But I strongly recommend that you use link-local addresses as next hops whenever possible.